# Reformat Numbers like 1111-2222-3333-4444 starting form left to right

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want this code to mark and sign between 4 digits from left but this code sign between 4 digit from right to left.

```
\B(?=(\d{4})+(?!(\d)))
```

The [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1puTyI/1)

[image]

I want reformat number like 1111-2222-3333-4444 and place '-' in real-time when user typing, user start type 4 digits and when they type 5th digit regex reformat to 1111-2 and ... 1111-222 and ... 1111-2222-33.

```
\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

With the `,` replacement, in JS, this regex reformats number format in real-time typing like 1,111 and 11,111,111 and more.

I want do that same but from left to right.

Comment: See the `Substitution` part [here](https://regex101.com/r/1puTyI/2)

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/xh2A8i/1

Comment: Something like this - [https://regex101.com/r/1puTyI/5](https://regex101.com/r/1puTyI/5)?

Comment: thnaks @ThomasAyoub , but that same my regex, it marks from right, i want that mark signs from left.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, but your code marks group of 4digit, i want it mark between of 4digit, in javascript if i replace digits will gone

Comment: @AndreiOdegov in your code it mark first number after 4digit from right. it's bad!!

Comment: Look at it - [https://regex101.com/r/1puTyI/6](https://regex101.com/r/1puTyI/6).

Comment: @AndreiOdegov Really thank u, excalty what i want, <3

Comment: @AndreiOdegov, u can post answer to mark it for answer of my question?!

Comment: You did not say it was in JavaScript. Just use `.replace(/\d{4}(?!$)/g, '$&-')`

Comment: @MahdiNamvari, this is not so important, and I think that it will not be entirely correct in relation to other participants in the discussion. I'm glad I helped you. But if you want to raise my rating, you can vote for any other my post that you may like :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
s = s.replace(/\d{4}(?!$)/g, '$&-')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uXkLW6/1).

The `\d{4}(?!$)` matches four digits not at the end of the string and `$&-` replaces with the match value and a `-`.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['1111222233334444','111122223333444','11112222333344','1111222233334','111122223333','11111','9999'];
var rx = /\d{4}(?!$)/g;
for (var i=0; i<strs.length;i++) {
  console.log(strs[i], '=>', strs[i].replace(rx, '$&-'));
}
```